# Add VPN connection greyed out in network manager (Kubuntu)

Tags: vpn, kubuntu

Try as I might, I can't get the "add" button in the VPN section of the Network Manager to not be greyed out.

Any ideas?  I've installed all the PPTP & OpenVPN packages that people have suggested.  And I've also defaulted the network interfaces file.  Still grey.

I'm using Kubuntu 10.04 and have also done all the recent dist-upgrades etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case others read this.

I never did get the PPTP VPN working in Network Manager under Kubuntu 10.04.  The Add button was always greyed out.

But, today I upgraded to 10.10 Maverick Meerkat release and it's now available.  So it seems the answer is to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install plugins for the network manager, I don't know what they're called in ubuntu, but the pptp plugin in debian is for example called 'network-manager-pptp-gnome' (that's with gnome UI). This has a dependency on PPTP so you don't need to install that explicitly.

HTH.

Comment: Did all of this.  It hasn't helped.